# Verizon-compatible USB data card with send/receive SMS support

Tags: usb, 4g

Some time ago, I had successfully used both 3G and 4G USB data cards on Verizon's network for mobile data access, as well as being able to natively send and receive SMS messages.

Verizon's only current USB offering - their MiFi 4G LTE data card (Novatel USB620L) - apparently does not support sending SMS messages from the card.

I had received a reply back from Verizon's Business & Government Customer Operations Support (Issue Tracking No. 98051-080116) as such:

> I got final word back from our device team that we do not support SMS through AT commands.

... which reflects what I also received back from Novatel technical support (reference INC0234732) as such:

> We have got the responce from our engineering team that Mobile Originated SMS is NOT supported on USB620L.

The frustrating aspect of this is that I thought this was considered "core" 4G functionality.  Verizon had also published a "Linux Integration Guide" for this card at http://www.verizonwireless.com/dam/support/pdf/user_guide/u620-linux-integration-guide-7-17-15.pdf - which was one of the primary reasons we chose this card and solution through VZW, as this connectivity was intended for a Linux device.

It also still "works" in that I can send a SMS message such that it is received by another phone - but in doing so, the serial console hangs for another ~3 minutes before finally returning:

```
+CMS ERROR: 500
```

I can repeat the same with the gammu command-line tool provided specifically for working with SMS (vs. hacking the manual "AT" commands).  Further details were posted to https://community.verizonwireless.com/message/1451434 at the beginning of the month - which is still unanswered as of this posting.  (Given that the focus of this site is for a hardware recommendation and not troubleshooting, I won't repeat the additional problem report details here.)

Verizon has tried to steer me to using their their Enterprise Messaging or other online solutions.  These are largely restricted to or at least prefer messaging to only other VZW subscribers.  They also require data access and additional integration work, where SMS would hopefully be a bit more standard and robust.

---

**Is there a currently supported 4G USB data card that works on Verizon's network for mobile data access, as well as supporting native sending and receipt of SMS messages?**

Support under Linux would be most preferable - but even with a "Windows-only" solution, I'm guessing I could also get it working under Linux (provided firmware-level support).